# Get JSON data as per UserId

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http, ios7

I can see the History of 30 user id by this url

```
http://userhistory.in/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLog?UserId=30
```

but Here the userid is mutable its generated based on the user registration. I just tried below code to get the history. but instead of 30 user its returning all users history.

```
NSString *userID2=@"30";
    int i=[userID2 intValue];


    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLog?%d",i];
    NSLog(@"url : %@",urlString);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
```

Here am passing the user id statically. If the code works fine then i'll get it from Registration response.apart from this I need to get the specific userid history.

Comment: I guess, there's something wrong with your server DB, API developer not filtering the users history result. `SELECT * FROM USER_HISTORY;` instead of ``SELECT * FROM USER_HISTORY WHERE USER_ID=30;` No issue with the app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your url

```
 NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLog?%d",i];
```

into

```
NSString *userID2=@"30";
int i=[userID2 intValue];

this is for int method

  NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLog?UserId=%d",i];
```

other wise 
       this is for string method

```
  NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLog?UserId=%@", userID2];


[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
```

Comment: @Hemang why u given the down vote, can u see the url , the key userid is missing

Comment: There should not be space in URL

Comment: @Apurv - I should submit the code for missing key, I updated my answer, thanks for given the information